# Remove Nullish values from multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, filter

I have an array `res` with some nullish values, and I have a function `remove` that is supposed return an array with nulls and undefined removed, but I can't get it to work on my array. I've seen plenty of answers on this sort of thing, in fact my `remove` function originated from one of them, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
res =    
[
{
    "1yKKftO0iOyvsacrW1mEr-FylurU8-fwaefewafw": [
        "raggy@champ.co",
        "grope@champ.co",
        null,
        "halp@champ.co"
    ]
},
{
    "149Lmt-gweagewfrthjregjiojoinONEDOnonao": [
        "raggy@champ.co"
    ]
},
{
    "JG043AHF0GJA0EWJIFJO00WIJF-UffFWEAk8QRg4": [
        "wlyman@champ.co",
        "raggy@champ.co"
    ]
},
{
    "1u-Frw5I4agI-FWKE0AFJ0WEJG0JEFDALKFEWA-ns": [
        null,
        "raggy@champ.co"
    ]
},
{
    "FAWGETAIODIOFAIJDSOIFJWEOFijewaofifejowef": [
        "raggy@champ.co"
    ]
},
{
    "fwaejf0JF0EWJIJFFJMojfeoijfewJEJFI0i0fje": [
        "raggy@champ.co"
    ]
},
{
    "FJ09Ejf093ejfie0jfeiJFEJF0IWJFEIJFOEJWow": [
        "raggy@champ.co"
    ]
}
]

var remove = function (array) {
var result = [];

array.forEach(function (item) {
  if (Array.isArray(item) && item.length!=0) {
    // Item is a nested array, go one level deeper recursively
    result.push(remove(item));
  }
  else if (typeof item !== null) {
    result.push(item);
  }
});

return result;
};

console.log(remove(res));
```

Comment: What's the desired output? The same as the input structure, but without the `null`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without recursion that will work for the nesting level given in example. Also will work if a single array element has multiple key value pairs.

```js
let res =[{"1yKKftO0iOyvsacrW1mEr-FylurU8-fwaefewafw": ["raggy@champ.co","grope@champ.co",null,"halp@champ.co"]},{"149Lmt-gweagewfrthjregjiojoinONEDOnonao": ["raggy@champ.co"]},{"JG043AHF0GJA0EWJIFJO00WIJF-UffFWEAk8QRg4": ["wlyman@champ.co","raggy@champ.co"]},{"1u-Frw5I4agI-FWKE0AFJ0WEJG0JEFDALKFEWA-ns": [undefined,"raggy@champ.co"]},{"FAWGETAIODIOFAIJDSOIFJWEOFijewaofifejowef": ["raggy@champ.co"]},{"fwaejf0JF0EWJIJFFJMojfeoijfewJEJFI0i0fje": ["raggy@champ.co"]},{"FJ09Ejf093ejfie0jfeiJFEJF0IWJFEIJFOEJWow": ["raggy@champ.co",null]}]

var remove = function (array) {

return array.map(function (item) {
  let x = Object.entries(item).map((y) => {
    return [y[0],y[1].filter((z)=> z!==undefined && z!==null)]
  })
  return Object.fromEntries(x)
});
};

console.log(remove(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `null`s as well as `undefined`s, you probably want to replace `else if (typeof item !== null)` with `else if (typeof item != null)`

Answer (score 1):

## What's happening

The elements of `res` are Objects.
Notice that in the nested function call of `remove`

```js
result.push(remove(item));
```

the `item` being passed are elements of `res` thus not an array. So when `remove(item)` is called the check `Array.isArray(item)` fails and nothing is sorted out.
To get the inner array make add this line.

```js
var values = Object.values(item)
```

Now handle the cases of item being `null`, `Object` and `Array`.

## Solution

Here's my Attempt at the solution. (I hope you don't mind ES6)
This does work on this particular (not sure about other cases)

```js
const remove = (item) => {
  if (item) {
    console.log('not null', item)
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      const result = []
      for (let elem of item) {
        const cleanedElem = remove(elem)
        // Maybe use Nullish coalescing operator ?
        if (cleanedElem !== null && cleanedElem !== undefined)
          result.push(cleanedElem)
      }
      return result
    } else if (typeof item === 'string' || typeof item === 'number') {
      return item
    } else if (item) {
      const result = {}
      for (let pair of Object.entries(item)) {
        const [key, value] = pair
        const cleanedValue = remove(value)
        // Maybe use Nullish coalescing operator ?
        if (cleanedValue !== null && cleanedValue !== undefined)
          result[key] = remove(cleanedValue)
      }
      return result
    }
  }
}

cleansed = remove(res)
console.log(cleansed);
```